# Http_parser depreciated warning in angular

Tags: angular, json-server

Recently I was working with client-server communication with Angular. There I need to use json server and it didn't allow to run on node version < v12.0.So I update my node version from v11.7.0 to node v19.0 and then I am facing this error.

```
(node:5512) [DEP0111] DeprecationWarning: Access to process.binding('http_parser') is deprecated.
(Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
** Angular Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200/ **
 10% building 4/5 modules 1 active ...t\index.js?http://0.0.0.0:0/sockjs-nodenode:internal/crypto/hash:71
  this[kHandle] = new _Hash(algorithm, xofLen);
```

Answer (score 0):

**The incompatibility of node version is causing this issue**

In my case I have update it to v19.0 from 11.9.0 as json doesn't run on node version <v12.
So I downgrade my node version using choco which is a great CLI for providing a number of popular software.

Just go to the terminal,

```
choco uninstall nodejs
choco install nodejs --version 12.9.1
```